# Unbounded Knapsack: Does Increasing capacity increase optimal value?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete, np, subset-sum, complexity-theory

Our decision problem is as follows: given weights $\mathbf{w}$, values $\mathbf{v}$, and capacities $C_1$ and $C_2$, where $C_1 < C_2$, does the optimal value of unbounded knapsack with the above values and weights change when we increase the capacity from $C_1$ to $C_2$?

Spent some time thinking about it, but can't get a straightforward reduction. I figure if we can get a reduction for the above for 0-1 knapsack, then it's easy to reduce / adapt the reduction to unbounded knapsack.